# How to use dynamic import of next js with path stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using dynamic import in next js. The component is rendered when I directly use the path. But it is not rendering when I use the path from a variable.

```
const faq = dynamic(() => import('../faq/faq'))
```

This works fine. but,

```
const path = '../faq/faq';
const faq = dynamic(() => import(path ))
```

This is not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As Per [webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)  It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as `import(foo)`. Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.

Answer (score -1):

You can use string concatenation while importing dependencies from variable

```
const path = '../faq/faq';
const faq = dynamic(() => import(`${path}` ))
```

Comment: along with dynamic import, you can use suspense or loading fallback based on your react version.